# Why do we ignore the significant digit for 2-word and 2 significant digit for 4-word?

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-cache

Imagine there are 3 direct-mapped cache designs possible, all with total 8-words of data: C1 has 1-word, C2 has 2 -words block, and C3 has 4-word blocks. Assume the sequence of memory accesses is 3,180,43,2,191,88,190...etc

a) Draw a table with each reference being a row and decimal address, binary address, index, tag,Hit or miss.

I understand that $$2^3$$ is the total word,  and C1 - 1 word will have 8  # of blocks so we can just do 3 mod 8  = 3 in binary its 011
but
for C2 there is 4 Blocks but yet 3 mod 8 = 01   and we ignored the 1 from previous. why do we do that?

Comment: Perhaps you should review class material.

Comment: i review all my class material they didn't have a slide on  words, and i read the textbook since 2 days ago  not really sure what i can do with word , like i know u need to do Main memory to cache by direct mapping we use    x mod n  however i don't know wat 1-word would be